# Who first invented/proposed/formulated the IQM (Interquartile Mean) and the Truncated/Trimmed Mean?

Tags: robust, mathematical-statistics, history

I've looked this up on google for quite some time but couldn't find the answer! Does any of you know who or how can I find who first proposed these statistics?

How can access their respective scientific articles or books?

Comment: The fullest history I know is within https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0313 to which I can add a mention of trimmed mean (_avant la lettre_) in Jules Verne, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twenty_Thousand_Leagues_Under_the_Sea

Comment: Thank you very much!!! That was exactly what I was looking for!! Impressive that you know this 'avant la lettre' reference as well, thank you for the recollection!!